# SharePoint Rest-API error with files >200 MB

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I using Microsoft SharePoint REST API at SharePoint Online and try to upload a pandas `DataFrame as csv`. If I write the `DataFrame` to a local csv file and start the Upload this works fine (also with big files).

Now I try to upload the `DataFrame` directly from Memory and get an error for files greater than 200 MB:

```py
output = io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.writer(output)
df.to_csv(output, **kwargs)


guid = str(uuid.uuid4()) # unique ID for identifying current upload
file_full_path = r"/sites/" + self._site_name + "/" + lib_name + "/" + folder_path + "/" + file_name
offset = 0
file_size = output.__sizeof__()
next_buffer = True


url = self._URL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + lib_name + "/" + folder_path + "')/Files/add(url = '" + file_name + "')"
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, proxies=self._proxies)           
        
#init uploading
url = self._URL + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='" + file_full_path + "')/StartUpload(uploadId=guid'" + guid + "')"
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, proxies=self._proxies) 

#read file and upload it in a bytestream according to the given chunk size 
while next_buffer:
    actual_offset = offset
    offset += chunksize    
    # continue uploading in chunks as long as the upcoming chunk is smaller than the actual file.
    # otherwise finish uploading by decreasing the chunk size to the number of bytes left.
    if offset >= file_size:
        chunksize = file_size - (offset - chunksize)
        next_buffer = False
        url = self._URL + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='" + file_full_path + "')/FinishUpload(uploadId=guid'" + guid + f"',fileOffset={actual_offset})"
    else:
        url = self._URL + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='" + file_full_path + "')/ContinueUpload(uploadId=guid'" + guid + f"',fileOffset={actual_offset})"
    # read current chunk and add it to the request 
    output.seek(actual_offset)
    buffer = output.read(chunksize)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = buffer, proxies=self._proxies)
```

This is the Error message:

```
error":{"code:"-2130575135, Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPBITSSessionIncompleteException
```

I don't understand why i get this error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the API a few months ago and if I remember correctly, the uploading request has to be PUT.
The general way to go is to create an [uploadSession](https://https:/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) and once you get the `uploadSessioUrl`, you PUT chunks of your document until you're finished.

[Microsoft Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors) as useful as always